# Changing expected `audience` in firebase-admin's verifyIdToken

Tags: node.js, google-signin, firebase-admin

We are trying to implement a [Google Sign-In button](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) in our mobile app and send the [idToken](https://auth0.com/docs/security/tokens/id-tokens) to our `NodeJS` server to complete the authentication process. The generation of the `idToken` on the mobile app works as expected but the verification of the token on the server-side with [firebase-admin](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) throws an audience mismatch error.

### Method #1

Using the [google-auth-library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) in our NodeJS server works as expected (minimal example):

```js
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';

const client = new OAuth2Client(credentials.client_id);

(async () => {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: token,
            audience: [
                credentials.client_id,
                'xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com',   <===== clientId added here
            ],
        });

    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
    console.log(payload); //  GOOD! idToken verification successful!
})();
```

It works because we are manually adding the mobile's `client id` which is specified in the `google-services.json` of the mobile app.

### Method #2

As we rather be using the [firebase-admin](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) package, we are wondering whether a similar `audience` addition can be made to the SDK's `verifyIdToken` method. Currently this does *NOT* work:

```js
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = fs.readJsonSync('./service-account.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

(async () => {
    const userInfo = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
    console.log(userInfo);  // ERROR! Verification throws error!
})();
```

It throws the following error:

> Error: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "xyz-123" but got "xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com".  Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project  as the service account used to authenticate this SDK

We've made several attempts with:

1. changing the m`clientId` in the `Sign-In with Google` component on mobile.
2. Changing the values in the `nodeJs` service account.

The result of those attempts was either the token was not being generated or we encountered the described mismatch verification error.

Regarding adding the audience value manually as described under **Method #1**, it seems the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/6c7c326e2c60bc06dcfa6a9fade4b187e21cdb9b/src/auth/auth.ts#L132) does not offer a way to supply more audiences.

1. Could there be reason why the option to add audiences is omitted in `firebase-admin` and available in `google-auth-library`?
2. Is there a different way to change the expected `audiences` while verifying `id tokens` with the `firebase-admin` package?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem and solved it by using

```
// gets firebase id token
const idToken = await result.user.getIdToken();
```

instead of

```
// gets original id token
const idToken = await GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result).idToken;
```